# Search a given string in a sorted array of Strings in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, search

I have written a program that searches for a String in a Sorted Array of Strings. My Program works fine except for the times when there are empty strings in my array. Below is the code:

```
public class StringSearch {

public static int binarySearchString(String[] s, String search)
{   

     int low = 0;
     int high = s.length-1;
     int mid;

     while(low<=high)
     {  mid = (high+low)/2;
         if(search.compareTo(s[mid])<0)
             high = mid-1;
         else if(search.compareTo(s[mid])>0)
             low = mid+1;
         else
             return mid;

     }
     return -1;

 }
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

     String[] str = {"abc", "", "def", "ijk", "mnop", "xyz"};
     String toSearch = new String("ijk");
     int result = binarySearchString(str, toSearch);
       if(result == -1)
          System.out.println("String not found!!");
       else
          System.out.println("String found at array index:" + result);
 }

 }
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Binary search won't work with arrays that aren't sorted.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by _"except for the times when there are empty strings "_.  What happens? If the array is sorted, where are the empty strings? How did you sort the array?

Comment: Techincally isn't sorted if there is a blank String randomly in there...

Comment: I got where I was wrong.. Thank you guys.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your array is not actually sorted: the empty string should come first in the array.

However, having said that, your test case of "ijk" should still work as it is after the mid point so avoids the unsorted section of the array.

So I ran your code and it correctly returns

```
String found at array index:3
```

It does not work in searching for "".

Add `Arrays.sort(str)` before the call `binarySearchString`.